# How can I convert Cubase projects to something more portable without Cubase?

Tags: cubase

I have some tracks made with Cubase SX 2 some years ago. Now, I want to work on them a bit, but I have no Cubase and even no ability to install it. So, I'm looking for any software that can convert these *.cpr's to some more portable format (maybe midi, or lilypond, or gtp, or at least print the score sheets). Ideally, it should work on *nix-like OS.

Is there something I'm looking for?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't done this with Cubase as I don't use it, what should work in general is to open with a trial version then save to some other format.

You could try using the [Cubase Elements 6 trial version](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/trial_version.html) to open your old `.cpr` files and save as Standard MIDI Files `.mid`, which virtually anything can open.

P.S. The reason I say Cubase *Elements* 6 because it looks like the trial version for "big" Cubase 6 requires you to purchase a USB copy protection dongle:

> Please note that you require a USB-eLicenser to activate the license
>   and start Cubase 6 Trial. You may purchase a USB-eLicenser from our
>   online shop or your local dealer (in case you already own a previous
>   version of Cubase or another product with a USB-eLicenser, you may use
>   this one instead).

Comment: That's a good news. I was sure Cubase trials are limited in functionality, and save/export is one of the disabled features. OK, now I have to find windows machine. Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's good news. As I mentioned I haven't actually done this; my answer was suggesting something to try. If it turns out the Cubase trials are save-disabled and this doesn't work for you, I certainly won't be offended if you don't mark my answer as `Accepted`. :)  Anyway I hope it does work.